# how to display chart in a Jpanel with Jframe

Tags: java, swing, charts, jframe, jpanel

So First, my chart generating code is:

```
class Cv implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


          while(true){ 
              try {
                  List<Date> PAdate = getPADate();
                  List<Integer> PAdata = getPAData();

                  int count =getRows();
                  final XYChart chart =   new XYChart(count,count);

                  final SwingWrapper sw = new SwingWrapper(chart);
                  XYSeries series =  chart.addSeries("PA",PAdate,PAdata);


                  chart.setHeight(500);
                  chart.setWidth(1500);

                  chart.setTitle("Courbes en temps réel des paramètres capturées");
                  chart.setXAxisTitle("Date");chart.setYAxisTitle("Paramètre");

                  sw.displayChart("Paramètre");
                  Thread.sleep(10000);
              } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(Cv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }

       }

        }}
```

this method belongs to the class which implements ActionListener, so i want to execute this class with pressing on the button in Jframe panel. I try with the flowing code but the chart is not appearing in the panel but the class is succesfuly executing:

```
public class SimpleRealTime extends JComponent{
    private JFrame  visualiser = new JFrame("Visualiser les paramètres");
    private JPanel  pane       = new JPanel();
    private JButton courbe     = new JButton("Courbe pression");
    private JButton quitter    = new JButton("Quitter");
    public SimpleRealTime() {
    visualiser.setSize(500,500);
    visualiser.setVisible(true);
    visualiser.add(pane);
    pane.add(courbe);
    pane.add(quitter);   
    courbe.addActionListener(new Cv());
    quitter.addActionListener(new Ferme());  
}
```

So can someone help me plz!
and what can i write in the main method?
thank you.

Comment: ?? `while(true){` -- Swing GUI code should never have something like this within an ActionListener. Remember that the library is an ***event-driven*** GUI library, and so you want to respond to *events*, not continually poll. This sort of code will freeze your GUI.

Comment: Same with `Thread.sleep(10000);`. Please read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see why this is dangerous code.

Comment: Without using the jframe, the swing chart is executed many time to show the insert data in reel time. that why i wrote the while loop.

Comment: Please read the link that I've given you to see why that code absolutely will not do what you're trying to get it to do.

Comment: And Thread.sleep(10000); is the time separating each chart

Comment: Ok , I will, thanks.

Comment: When you press your courbe JButton, does the application freeze?

Comment: Yes you can say that, now I deleted the while loop and Thread.sleep instruction and the chart appear in another window but it will be static not dynamic.

Comment: Then check out the solutions to similar questions and consider using a SwingWorker.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: http://knowm.org/how-to-make-real-time-charts-in-java/ It uses SwingWorker.